# How to dynamically update a value in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

thanks for looking at my question! I am trying to dynamically update some values in a Pandas DataFrame using the values that already exist in the DataFrame.

I know that I can use the `loc` method to do a look up and update the values I find to something static. For example:

```py
import pandas as pd

customers = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3],
                          'name': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo'],
                          'balance': [100, 200, -300]})

customers.loc[(customers['name']=='foo') & (customers['id']==3), ['balance']] = 300

print(customers)
# {'id': [1, 2, 3], 'name': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo'], 'balance': [100, 200, 300]}
```

But I am trying to update the value dynamically using values that already exist in the DataFrame, something like:

```py
customers = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3],
                          'name': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo'],
                          'balance': [100, 200, -300]})


customers.loc[(customers['name']=='foo') & (customers['id']==1), ['balance']] = #abs('balance')
```

I would expect this to update all values from the `loc` query to be positive integers. Of course, this is a simple example with only one match :)

Is there a way to dynamically access/update values in a Pandas DataFrame like this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pandas` is `index` sensitive , so when you assign the value the hidden key is `index` ,it will match the `index` , so that you can just apply the condition once.

```
customers.loc[(customers['name']=='foo') & (customers['id']==1), ['balance']] =customers.balance.abs()
customers
Out[112]: 
   balance  id name
0      100   1  foo
1      200   2  bar
2      300   3  foo
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you happen to know where this is covered in the documentation so I can read more into it? I've had a rough time with the Pandas docs.